# Programmatically retrieving the MAC Address

Tags: android, network-programming, mac-address

I have a Zebra rugged Android device equiped with Android Marshmallow 6.0.
I tested two ways of retrieving Mac address in this website and none of them worked for me.
There is one using Wifimanager

```
public String getMacAddress(Context context) {
WifiManager wimanager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
String macAddress = wimanager.getConnectionInfo().getMacAddress();
if (macAddress == null) {
    macAddress = "Device don't have mac address or wi-fi is disabled";
}
return macAddress;
}
```

This one is impossible to compile the context.getSystemService causing compilation problems.

The other one using networkinterfaces that i will not post here entirely:
 List all = Collections.list(NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces());
        for (NetworkInterface nif : all)
The result is  an exit with exception.
I tried to understand why and it seems as soon as the code try to get the network interfaces the exceptions happens!

The manufacturer equip the hardware with his own driver called Fusion but I went through their sdk available here http://techdocs.zebra.com but there is no specific sdk command to retrieve the MacAddress.
If anyone could bring me some suggestions, it would be great and I would be very grateful.

Comment: could you put your manifest file

Comment: Hi & thanks for your attention. I can't post manifest file into the text zone: is it a way I can upload the file here?

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

Comment: I posted the permissions above: Is that what you wanted to see?